# Linq Select: Set specific value for first occurrence only

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way in Linq of setting a value for the first selected occurrence matching the condition?

I know I'm not explaining this well, but for example:

```
var mySelectedObjects = allMyObjects.OrderBy(o.Date).Select(o => new ObjectType 
{
    Element1 = o.Element1,
    Element2 = o.Element2,
    Date = o.Date,
    BooleanElement = o.BooleanElement && ThisIsTheFirstTrue
};
```

So in the above example, the desired output result is that in `mySelectedObjects` the `BooleanElement` item would only be true for the *first* occurence of `allMyObjects` (ordered by `Date`) where it's true, and the rest would all be false regardless of their values in `allMyObjects`.

i.e. I only want one (the earliest) occurrence with `BooleanElement` = true in `mySelectedObjects`. What should I replace `ThisIsTheFirstTrue` with?

*Edit*

I realise this can be done with a `for` loop after the select but I'm hoping to do it all within the Select.

Anyway just to clarify in response to suggestions. I want it to be true for the first occurrence where it's true in the input, not just the first occurrence, so for example if the input data is...

```
false
true
false
true
true
false
```

I want the output to be

```
false
true
false
false
false
false
```

Comment: For your edit - why other two `true` values gone in output?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - that is the requirement for what I'm trying to do. (In this case the boolean value is bound to a `Visibility` attribute in a XAML form and I only want to display one item each time)

Comment: Does this functionality have to be implemented in the Select or is a general Linq based approach sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So using `Linq` :

```
bool found = false;
var mySelectedObjects = objects
    .OrderBy(o => o.Date)
    .Select(o => new ObjectType 
    {
        Element1 = o.Element1,
        Element2 = o.Element2,
        Date = o.Date,
        BooleanElement = !found && o.BooleanElement ? (found = true) : false
    }
);
```

[Online check](http://rextester.com/BEMY67607)

Comment: Oh that's a clever inlining compared to my answer :)

Comment: I started writing this when there was one answer. but I'm currently @ workplace so I have some things to do other than just answering :)

Comment: I don't like modifying local variables in a LINQ query as a side effect.You might get unexpected results if someone changes the query slightly

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's true but if you're the one responsible for this piece then I think it doesn't matter if it is inside Linq  query or in some other loop. Just have to remember what it's doing :) For me the best answer is posted by you and that's the one that should be used in production.

Comment: @m.rogalski: if i need such tricks it's clearly a sign to avoid LINQ for this task. Or at least use it only for the ordering

Answer (score 2):

I would assign it in a loop, not elegant but working:

```
var mySelectedObjects = allMyObjects
    .OrderBy(o.Date)
    .Select(o => new ObjectType 
    {
       Element1 = o.Element1,
       Element2 = o.Element2,
       Date = o.Date,
       BooleanElement = o.BooleanElement
    });

bool firstTrueFound = false;
foreach(ObjectType o in mySelectedObjects)
{
    if(o.BooleanElement)
    {
        if(firstTrueFound) 
            o.BooleanElement = false;
        else
            firstTrueFound = true;
    }
}
```

The only LINQ solution that comes into my mind isn't as efficient, look:

```
var boolLookup = allMyObjects.ToLookup(o => o.BooleanElement);
var mySelectedObjects = boolLookup[true]
    .OrderBy(o => o.Date)
    .Select((o, index) => new ObjectType
    {
        Element1 = o.Element1,
        Element2 = o.Element2,
        Date = o.Date,
        BooleanElement = index == 0
    })
    .Concat(boolLookup[false])
    .OrderBy(o => o.Date);
```

Comment: what about a let in a linq query?

Comment: @Mafii: what kind of `let`? In query syntax you don't even get an index in the select(as opposed to method syntax where you can use the overload of select which gives the index). But that index doesn't help because you want the index of the first occurence of `BooleanElement` in an ordered query.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for, that is, checking the index of an item from within `Select` is not possible (actually is, by operating over a list and calling `IndexOf`, but that's quadratic in terms of running costs, so I wouldn't suggest that). However, note that inside the `select`, you don't necessarily have to write an object creation expression, you can write a code block as well. This way, the following will work:

```
bool found = false;
var mySelectedObjects = allMyObjects.OrderBy(o.Date).Select(o =>
{
    var booleanElement = !found && o.BooleanElement;
    found = booleanElement;

    var result = new ObjectType
    {
        Element1 = o.Element1,
        Element2 = o.Element2,
        Date = o.Date,
        BooleanElement = booleanElement
    };

    return result;
});
```

This is the most LINQish way of solving it that I can provide you with.

To address the comment of @TheJP, here is a way to go over the issue of parallelism:

Let's create a class like this:

```
class TrueOnlyOnFirstAccess
{
    private bool val = true;
    private object valLock = new object();
    public bool Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!val) return false;

            lock (valLock)
            {
                if (!val) return false;

                val = false;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is when the value is first requested, it will return `true` for the first time, and within a locking context, changes the value to `false`. Since once the value is false, it should never change, we can safely return false if we find the backing field to be false, therefore avoiding unnecessary lockings. How to use it:

```
TrueOnlyOnFirstAccess switcher = new TrueOnlyOnFirstAccess();
items.Select(item => new
{
    // other props
    BooleanElement = item.BooleanElement && switcher .Value
})
```

Here we exploit the lazy nature of logical `and` - that is, `item.BooleanElement` *must* be the first to evaluate, if that is false, `sw.Value` will not be called, and the backing field will therefore not be changed. Use it with caution in more complex expressions.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is not pure / has side effects. This would cause problems if you would want to run it in parallel for example. Otherwise it is the best solution so far.

Comment: Absolutely, though it was never said parallelism was a requirement.

Comment: Well, this is not really LINQ. The Select part should be in a foreach